# What is the permutation representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, permutations, representation-theory, finite-fields

It seems that there is a action by which $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ permute the $p^2$ ordered tuples in $\mathbb{F}_p^2$. What is the map from the $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p$ versions of the elements of these groups to the elements of $S_{p^2}$ that this action picks out?

Similarly there seems to be an injective homomorphism map from $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ to $S_{p+1}$ by virtue of the natural action on $\mathbb{F}_pP^1$ (the projective space obtained from $\mathbb{F}_p^2$)
What is this mapping?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've already described these maps.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan See my comments to Herbert's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix $A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right] \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ acts on a vector $v = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} v_0 \\ v_1 \end{array} \right] \in \mathbb{F}_p^2$ by matrix multiplication:

$$Av = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} v_0 \\ v_1 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a v_0 + b v_1 \\ c v_0 + d v_1 \end{array} \right].$$

This is far and away the best description of this action I can give. You can figure out everything you could possibly want to know about this action from linear algebra. It is even better than knowing a permutation representation because linear algebra is easier than set theory, even finite set theory.

For example, here is how you figure out the cycle decomposition of the permutation corresponding to $A$. It splits into cases depending on the conjugacy class of $A$ as follows.

**Case:** $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then up to conjugacy it is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_0, \lambda_1 \in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$. Its order is the lcm of the orders $d_i$ of $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$, which can be any divisor of $p - 1$. The corresponding permutation of $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ fixes zero and splits the nonzero vectors into cycles as follows:

- The nonzero vectors of the form $(v_0, 0)$ form cycles of length $d_0$.
- The nonzero vectors of the form $(0, v_1)$ form cycles of length $d_1$.
- The remaining nonzero vectors form cycles of length $\text{lcm}(d_0, d_1)$.

**Case:** $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ but not over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then up to conjugacy its action on $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ is the action of multiplication by an element $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}^{\times}$ (one of the eigenvalues of $A$) on $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. Its order is the order $d$ of $\lambda$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^{\times}$, which can be any divisor of $p^2 - 1$. The corresponding permutation of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ fixes zero, and the nonzero vectors form cycles of length $d$.

**Case:** $A$ is not diagonalizable even over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. From the theory of [rational canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) we deduce that up to conjugacy $A$ is a Jordan block

$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{array} \right]$$

where $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$. Its order is $p$ times the order $d$ of $\lambda$, which can be any divisor of $p - 1$. The corresponding permutation of $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ fixes zero and splits the nonzero vectors into cycles as follows:

- The nonzero vectors of the form $(v_0, 0)$ form cycles of length $d$.
- The remaining nonzero vectors form cycles of length $pd$.

The analysis for the action on the projective line is similar. Writing a point on the projective line in projective coordinates $(v_0 : v_1)$, the action takes the form

$$A (v_0 : v_1) = (av_0 + bv_1 : cv_0 + dv_1)$$

or, thinking of an element of the projective line as a fraction $z = \frac{v_0}{v_1}$ (which may take the value $\infty$),

$$A z = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}.$$

Again you can figure out everything you could possibly want to know about this action from linear algebra as above. In the diagonalizable case, for example, projectively the action of a diagonal matrix with entries $d_0, d_1$ is multiplication by $\frac{d_0}{d_1}$, and hence its cycle decomposition is determined by the order of $\frac{d_0}{d_1}$. So things are even simpler.

Comment: @Qiachu Yuan Thanks for the help! Do you know what the irrep decomposition is of these permutation representations?

Comment: @Qiachu Yuan What I need is an enumeration of all the group elements of these groups, SL_2(F_q) or PSL_2(F_q) or GL_2(F_q) or PGL_2(F_q), so that I can do these calculations by hand for specific cases.  Is this somehow available?

Comment: @user6818: I don't know what you mean by the irrep decomposition of a permutation representation. The decomposition of $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ into orbits is that $0$ is an orbit and the nonzero vectors are the other orbit. The decomposition of $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ as a linear representation is that it's irreducible. I also don't know what you mean by an enumeration of all the group elements. You can just write down matrices and chuck out the ones that aren't invertible.

Comment: I am not understanding what you are not understanding :D  Here is an action of these groups on $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ (or on $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{F}_p^2 )$) so we have a representation of these groups on these vector spaces.  (so we have here basically listed out 6 representations) Are any of these irreducible? If not then what is the irrep decomposition of these representations?

Comment: @user6818: the grammar was throwing me off. "Irrep decomposition" is a term people apply to linear representations, not permutation representations (which I took to mean actions on sets). One thing you might have meant by "permutation representation" is the linear representation induced by an action on a set, which is different from the linear representation on $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ that we're talking about, so I found that ambiguous. Anyway, the projective line is not a vector space, but the action of $\text{GL}_n$ on an $n$-dimensional vector space is always irreducible.

Comment: What we have defined here are group actions for SL_2(F_p), PSL_2(F_p), GL_2(F_p) and PGL_2(F_p) on the vector space F_p^2? Right? Are any of these irreducible? If not what is their irrep decomposition?

Comment: @user6818: the projective groups do not act on $\mathbb{F}_p^2$; they only act on the projective line. The other two act irreducibly. I've said this twice already for $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and it's not much harder to show for $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Comment: (1) Both GL_2(F_q) and SL_2(F_q) have a (q+1)-dimensional representation on P(F_q^2) - agreed? (2) There is no irrep of GL_2(F_q) or SL_2(F_q) which is of dimension q^2 (as this permutation representation is)  then how can this be irreducible? (you can see  the irrep sizes here, http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_general_linear_group_of_degree_two_over_a_finite_field#Irreducible_representations, http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_special_linear_group_of_degree_two_over_a_finite_field#Irreducible_representations

Comment: @user6818: those tables refer to irreducible representations over $\mathbb{C}$. These are representations over $\mathbb{F}_q$. I still can't tell whether you are talking about group actions on sets $X$ or about their corresponding linear representations $\mathbb{C}[X]$.

Comment: If $X$ is a set with more than one element on which a group $G$ acts, then the corresponding linear representation $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is never irreducible: it always has a trivial quotient $\mathbb{C}[X] \to \mathbb{C}$ given by identifying every element of $X$. If $X$ is a (finite, for safety) set on which a group $G$ acts doubly transitively, then the kernel of this quotient map is an irreducible linear representation of $G$ (exercise). This is in particular the case when $X = \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_q)$ and $G = \text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ (exercise).

Comment: What is C(X)? Given the permutation action of G on X which is the |X| sized representation here?

Comment: For q a prime power, isn't the permutation action of GL_2(F_q) or SL_2(F_q) on F_q^2 giving a q^2 dimensional representation? I would like to break this into irreps over C - obviously.

Comment: @user6818: this is not obvious to me; you are still being confusing, but I think you are in fact talking about the linear representation $\mathbb{C}[X]$ and not the group action $X$. (This is the linear representation you get when you think of the action of $G$ on $X$ in terms of permutation matrices.) Like I said, this representation is never irreducible. The best you can hope for is that the kernel of the natural map $\mathbb{C}[X] \to \mathbb{C}$ is irreducible. When $X = \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_q)$ and $G = \text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$, this holds, as I said above.

Comment: A necessary condition for $\text{ker}(\mathbb{C}[X] \to \mathbb{C})$ to be irreducible is that $G$ acts transitively on $X$, and so things are even worse for $X = \mathbb{F}_q^2, G = \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$, where the action consists of two orbits; at the very least you should remove zero. I think the resulting representation is still not irreducible but I don't know off the top of my head what its irrep decomposition is. If this was what you actually wanted to know you should've said so, and you should ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{GL}_2 (\mathbb{F}_p)$ have a natural action on $\mathbb{P}_1(\mathbb{F}_p)$ : the action of $g$ on a vector line $d$ is just the vector line $g\cdot d$. Its kernel is the set of elements in $\mathrm{GL}_2 (\mathbb{F}_p)$ which stabilize every one-dimensional vector space and it is easy to show that this is the center of $\mathrm{GL}_2 (\mathbb{F}_p)$ (homotheties). Therefore, the quotient of $\mathrm{GL}_2 (\mathbb{F}_p)$ (which is $\mathrm{PGL}_2 (\mathbb{F}_p)$ ) is mapped to the permutation group of $\mathbb{P}_1(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and this is an injection.

As $\mathbb{P}_1(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has $1+q$ elements, this provides an injection
$$\mathrm{PGL}_2 (\mathbb{F}_p) \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{S}_{p+1}$$

For low $p$, this leads to so-called "exceptional isomorphisms", such as 
$$ \mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{F}_5) \simeq \mathfrak{S}_5 $$

Comment: I guess my question isn't clear! I want to know what these maps are! Like given a $2\times 2$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for any of these three groups, I want to know what is the permutation matrix that corresponds to it in this action.

Comment: It will depend on the basis of the underlying vector space.

Comment: Yes, obviously. But can you give me the action? As in given a $2 \times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}_p$ an element of say $SL_2(F_p)$ what is its action on some element say $(a,b) \in \mathbb{F}_p^2$ ?

Comment: And equivalently is there a way to explicitly enumerate all the elements of any of these groups?

Comment: @user6818: the way you phrase this question makes it unclear to me whether you know how a matrix acts on a vector. Is that all you're asking about?